# How to keep antialiasing in python tk application icon?

Tags: python, windows, tk-toolkit, photoimage

This is what I do to assign an icon shown in 'Alt-Tab' list to my python script.

```
   self.icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=iconpath)
   self.root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self.root._w, self.icon)
```

But it only works with .gif, which can't handle antialiasing for transparency correctly.

The same .ico file I created my .gif from looks perfect when assigned to .bat file for example.

Is there a way to make the `.py` script look not so much worse than `.bat` script in alt-tab menu?

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.root.iconbitmap(iconpath)
```

solved the issue (it accepts .ico - under Windows at least)